# 64 bit safety and uint32_t

Tags: ios, xcode, 32bit-64bit

I have the following code in an iOS app, which uses the Accelerate framework:

```
 NSUInteger radius = floor(inputRadius * 3. * sqrt(2 * M_PI) / 4 + 0.5);
            if (radius % 2 != 1) {
                radius += 1; // force radius to be odd so that the three box-blur methodology works.
            }
            vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888(&effectInBuffer, &effectOutBuffer, NULL, 0, 0, radius, radius, 0, kvImageEdgeExtend);
```

Xcode is showing a warning on the last line:

> Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSUInteger' (aka
>   'unsigned long') to 'uint32_t' (aka 'unsigned int')

Can I replace NSUInteger with uint32_t, even though I am converting the rest of this project to 64 and 32 bit safe code (mostly NSInteger instead of int, and the resulting method definition changes).

If not, how do I resolve the issue with NSUInteger?

Comment: There's nothing about fixed-size integer types that isn't "64 and 32 bit safe".  What hypothetical issue are you worried about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Change `radius` to `uint32_t` instead of `NSUInteger`.
2. If you know that `radius` will never be too big, cast `radius` to `uint32_t` in the call to `vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888`.

Comment: The best solution is to simply make radius an `uint32_t`; that's fairly safe here because a blur radius of 4 billion pixels is simply not going to happen.  If you wanted to be completely safe, you would clamp the double-precision computed value before converting it to integer.